# Edit html error on tumblr.

Tags: html, edit, tumblr

Why doesn't work the Edit Html section on Tumblr? When I go to the Customize section I click the edit html button and.. nothing happens. Could you help me please?

Comment: Please go check the FAQ on tumblr. This is a programming forum, someone could help you, but this question is not relevant to the purpose of stack overflow.

Answer (score -1):

If it still isn't working, you could also possibly try opening the site in a different browser.